# Rails search with where and geocode near at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, where-clause, geocode

Is there a way I could search with both a where condition and a near condition at the same time, showing results for both. Basically, I want a search bar where a user could enter a name of a person, but they could also enter a location and the search would show results that match both. I tried having the where query and then a separate near query and looping through the Geocoded results and adding them to the main results, but this creates repeats and is less than desirable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which geocoding gem are you using? My guess is that instead of doing `query.where.near` you can do a `query.where` where you set the equivalent options that the `near` selector generates.

This is a different question and one theoretically orthogonal to what you asked...but is your controller making any decisions before the query is passed onto ActiveRecord? For example, if a user types in `New York, NY`, does your controller "guess" that it is a location? Or does it just try to do a name-matching search AND a geocode attempt, no matter what the input is? I ask this because if you do parse out the input, you could have this be an if/else situation, where `if query is a location, do a geocode` or `else do a search by name`.

I wonder whether it's sensible design to have a search box that doesn't distinguish between a person's name and a location name before hitting the database, but maybe you have a creative use-case.

Comment: You make a good point. I am using the [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) and [this is the site](http://whoseyourlandlord.com/) that I'm working on. The problem with deciding if the query is a location before passing onto ActiveRecord is if a user searches for a college, they may put in Maryland which would match the name "University of Maryland", but is also a location. And if it is determined that Maryland is a location, University of Maryland might not be found depending on the proximity.

Comment: Ah...then perhaps you want to break out the search functionality so that typing in a partial name brings up an auto-complete for colleges. Such as, starting with "Uni..." or "Maryl..." brings up options including "University of Maryland". OTherwise, I guess you have to assess whether an omni-search box really adds that much more flexibility, given the extra logic (and possible database hits) you have to add.